# How to remove CALayer bottom border of UIButton in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton, calayer

How to remove CALayer bottom border of UIButton in Swift? Bottom border is added to week1 button but not removed when clicked on button week2.

I am adding screen shot also[image]

Here is my code:

```
     @IBAction func week1BtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            week1.isSelected = true
            didTapButton(btnClicked: week1)
            week2.isSelected = true
            didTapButton(btnClicked: week2)
            btnSelectedText = "Week-1"
            serviceCall()
        }

        @IBAction func week2BtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            week2.isSelected = true
            week1.isSelected = false
            didTapButton(btnClicked: week1)
            btnSelectedText = "Week-2"
            didTapButton(btnClicked: week2)
            serviceCall()
        }

      func didTapButton(btnClicked:UIButton){
          let border = CALayer()
            if btnClicked.isSelected {
            border.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: btnClicked.frame.size.height - 2.0, width:  btnClicked.frame.size.width - 5, height: btnClicked.frame.size.height)

            border.borderWidth = 3.0
            btnClicked.layer.addSublayer(border)
            btnClicked.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
           else{
             border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            border.borderWidth = 0.0
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: btnClicked.frame.size.height , width:  btnClicked.frame.size.width - 5, height: btnClicked.frame.size.height)
            btnClicked.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in the `week1BtnTapped`. The `isSelected` of `button2` should be `false`, so that the condition in `didTapButton` will work as you want.